# Backbone.js and rendering table

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js and I've been having a real problem. I want to list firstname and lastname of members and put them in a table. For some reasons, I'm missing an important point and it's not working. My code:

```
var members = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/get_members",
});

var member_collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : members,
    url : "/get_members",
});

var member_list_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('#members'),
    initialize : function() {
        this.collection.bind("add", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        var $tbody = this.$("tbody");
        _.each(this.model.models, function(data) {
            this.$el.append(new member_view({model : data}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

var member_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : "tr",
    template : _.template($("#member-template").html()),

    render : function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});



var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {"members" : "member_router"},
    member_router : function() {
        var member_colls = new member_collection();
        var member_viewer = new member_list_view({collection : member_colls});
        member_colls.fetch();
    }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="member-template">
<table id="members">
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Firstname</td><td>Lastname</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><%= firstname %></td><td><%= lastname %></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it's not working". There could be many reasons. Are your models correctly fetched? Are there any console errors?

Comment: No there isn't any console errors. What I meant by saying not working is nothing is rendered on browser. I've looked at console.log(model) to see if models are fetched from database and yes, they were so I'm guessing I'm missing something in views.

Comment: @Ivan learn to use Chrome's JS debugging tools.  Check out Tom Dale's great [talk](http://vimeo.com/37539737) on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. There are many problems with the above code:

1) Temaplate `member-template`

You use the member template for the `member_view` however it contains the entire table instead of just the member row. Your template should be like:

```
<script type="text/template" id="member-template">
    <td><%= firstname %></td><td><%= lastname %></td>
</script>​
```

2) `member_list_view` has `this.collection.bind` while `render()` uses `this.model.models`

You should have it consistent as:

```
var member_list_view = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('#members'),
    initialize : function() {
        this.model.bind("add", this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(data) {
            this.$el.append(new member_view({model : data}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

**For a full working version of your code, [take a look at this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6rYw/)**

Comment: You probably don't need $tbody there since you are already appending to a table... and jQuery kindly put it in the tbody already :)

Comment: `member_list_view` should be using `this.collection` and `new member_list_view({collection: ...})` since it is working with a collection rather than a model. And I'd use `this.collection.each(...)` instead of `_.each(this.collection.models, ...)` since [some Underscore methods are mixed into Backbone collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods).